# Outputting dfsrdiag command result with Out-File in Ps or >> in cmd produces an empty file

Tags: powershell, windows-server

I'm trying to output a result of

```
dfsrdiag backlog /rgname:"YourReplicationGroupName" /rfname:"YourReplicationFolderName" /sendingmember:"SenderServer" /receivingmember:"ReceiverServer"
```

into a file by appending Out-File in PS:

```
   dfsrdiag backlog /rgname:"YourReplicationGroupName" /rfname:"YourReplicationFolderName" /sendingmember:"SenderServer" /receivingmember:"ReceiverServer" | Out-File -FilePath "C:\Path\To\Your\File.txt"
```

or by appending >> in cmd

```
dfsrdiag backlog /rgname:"YourReplicationGroupName" /rfname:"YourReplicationFolderName" /sendingmember:"SenderServer" /receivingmember:"ReceiverServer" >> C:\temp\log.txt
```

**The command itself works and produces desired output, but when trying to redirect the output in both cases it produces an empty txt file.**

Interestingly, this command works fine on older OS, like Windows Server 2008 R2, but not on Windows Server 2022.I'd really appreciate help or any tips on what I'm doing wrong. Thanks.

Comment: I don't have that command.  Add `2>&1` ?

Comment: Nope, this doesn't work. There must be some issue with the command syntax itself, or just basically it means that the 'dfsrdiag' cmdline tool can't output to a file on newer OS for some strange reason. If I use another command, for ex $PSVersionTable, or Get-DFSRBacklog, it outputs to a file no problem (When using *>)

Comment: I also do not have that command, but what if you capture the output in a variable: `$out = $(dfsrdiag backlog /rgname:"YourReplicationGroupName" /rfname:"YourReplicationFolderName" /sendingmember:"SenderServer" /receivingmember:"ReceiverServer")` and then write that to file ?